# why is head.next printing the whole linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I was solving the problem in Leetcode. The problem is to combine two linked lists and return the final list. Link to the question is https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/. I thought that head.next is just pointing to one node of the whole linked list but returning head.next gives all the nodes of the linked list. Can you please explain to me why?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode curr = head;

        while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if (l1.val < l2.val) {
                curr.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                curr.next =l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }

        if (l1 != null) {
            curr.next = l1;
        } else if ( l2 != null) {
            curr.next = l2;
        }
        return head.next;
    }
}
```

So my test inputs are l1 =[1,2,4] , l2 = [1,3,4]. I was expecting to get just 1 because using sys.out(head.next) I get only 1, not the whole linked list.

Comment: `head.next` points to one node, which in turn points to the next etc. until the end of the list. But you know that already. Can you clarify what *specific* behavior you were surprised by? As is, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to print only the first value you should print `sys.out(head.val)`. The `head.next` is a reference to the next node

Comment: @shmosel Thank you for the reply. The head.next is not inside any loop. So I assumed that return `head.next` will just return the current value of `head.next`. I understand that they are connected but I was surprised why `head.next`  gives the whole LinkedList instead of just the giving the node the `head.next`  points to.

Comment: @ButiriDan Yes I understand that `head.next` is a reference to the next node. But why `head.next` is returning the whole LinkedList instead of just the node that it is referencing.

Comment: @AsimThapa They're not just "connected".  Java doesn't use pointers like C++ does.  The `next` value inside your head node doesn't just *point* to the next node:  It **is** the next node.  And inside of that object is its own `next` value, which contains the next node, etc.  So your head object actually contains all of the other objects in the linked list nested inside it.

Comment: `head.next` is both a single node and, indirectly, the entire remainder of the list. Again, please clarify what specific behavior you're surprised by.

Comment: @shmosel I am surprised by the **`head.next` is the entire remainder of the list** part. I thought it was only a single node of the whole list.

Comment: As I said, each node points to the next node, which points to the next, and so on, until the end of the list.

Comment: I feel like I have half knowledge about LinkedList. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave a similar reply in a comment, but hopefully some fancy formatting makes this a bit clearer.

Imagine the input list `[1,2,3]`.  When you create a linked list out of that, the `head` object looks like the following (represented as JSON):

```
{
    "val" : 1,
    "next" : {
        "val" : 2,
        "next" : {
            "val" : 3,
            "next": null
        }
    }
}
```

So the value of `head.next` is:

```
{
    "val" : 2,
    "next" : {
        "val" : 3,
        "next": null
    }
}
```

Note that, at every level of the linked list, the object you have holds the entire remainder of the list.  You can't just get a single node, because each node holds all of the remaining nodes inside of itself.

Comment: Yes. I get it now. Thank you for clarifying it.